# Old .qml style (vector-polygons) from QGIS 2.18 in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, qml

I have a .qml polygon style file created with QGIS 2.18. It works to import until Version 3.2 without problem. But in 3.4 the style is loaded, but not applied/visualized. The Polygons dissappear instead of being filled with my styles. See this comparison below. The left side is QGIS 3.4, right side QGIS 3.2

[image]

A snippet of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis version="2.18.5" simplifyAlgorithm="0" minimumScale="0" maximumScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingHints="1" minLabelScale="0" maxLabelScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingTol="1" readOnly="0" simplifyMaxScale="1" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0" simplifyLocal="1" scaleBasedLabelVisibilityFlag="0">
  <edittypes>
    <edittype widgetv2type="TextEdit" name="CODE">
      <widgetv2config IsMultiline="0" fieldEditable="1" constraint="" UseHtml="0" labelOnTop="0" constraintDescription="" notNull="0"/>
    </edittype>
    <edittype widgetv2type="TextEdit" name="CODEALT">
      <widgetv2config IsMultiline="0" fieldEditable="1" constraint="" UseHtml="0" labelOnTop="0" constraintDescription="" notNull="0"/>
    </edittype>
    <edittype widgetv2type="TextEdit" name="ELEM_ID">
      <widgetv2config IsMultiline="0" fieldEditable="1" constraint="" UseHtml="0" labelOnTop="0" constraintDescription="" notNull="0"/>
    </edittype>
  </edittypes>
  <renderer-v2 forceraster="0" symbollevels="0" type="RuleRenderer" enableorderby="0">
    <rules key="{ec0406f9-5dae-40a4-9134-8c7f04deebb3}">
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011101" key="{5754f788-5394-4164-90b2-e7e810d97fee}" symbol="0" label="Landwirtschaftsgebiet | Zona di verde agricolo"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011102" key="{f69ec5b0-a9a9-437e-b9ff-a2c292c30ddc}" symbol="1" label="Wald | Bosco"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011103" key="{ae76e505-9db2-41e5-b03e-56013a4a9fc8}" symbol="2" label="Bestockte Wiese und Weide | Prato e pascolo alberato"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011104" key="{0792eaf9-a36d-42eb-a986-b0a175a17074}" symbol="3" label="Alpines Grünland |  Zona di verde alpino "/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011201" key="{194d1ac3-bfb7-4ab4-bdfc-a1636b080be2}" symbol="4" label="Gewässer - Öffentliches Wassergut | Acque - Demaneo idrico"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1011202" key="{d101acd9-ae50-43f8-81a8-906f07d6e3f6}" symbol="5" label="Felsregion - Gletscher | Zona rocciosa - Ghiacciaio"/>
      <rule filter=" &quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012099 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012130" key="{ccb031de-7c81-4318-b671-69cda20bc4be}" symbol="6" label="Wohnbauzone A - Historischer Ortskern | Zona residenziale A - Centro storico"/>
      <rule filter=" &quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012129 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012160" key="{686e2656-fa8e-4096-b693-c5709719676f}" symbol="7" label="Wohnbauzone B - Auffüllzone | Zona residenziale B - Zona di completamento"/>
      <rule filter=" &quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012159 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012200" key="{6492dc4e-0414-4611-b992-3e080e3a09ab}" symbol="8" label="Wohnbauzone C - Erweiterungszone | Zona residenziale C - Zona di espansione"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012201" key="{993503b6-dca9-45c0-85a5-2be89c194ea0}" symbol="9" label="Private Grünzone | Zona di verde privato"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012211" key="{58e71d5b-a623-4d7b-bded-e754c37da51d}" symbol="10" label="Landwirtschaftliche Wohnsiedlung | Zona residenziale rurale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012212" key="{b9316012-2cbb-4459-aac9-29ca4b33f0dd}" symbol="11" label="Zone mit Plan für die Stadtebauliche Umstrukturierung – PSU | Zona con piano di riqualificazione urbana - PRU"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012301" key="{ccfd257a-4da0-42ac-8a98-6b9beab92c62}" symbol="12" label="Gewerbeerweiterungsgebiet | Zona di espansione per insediamenti produttivi"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012302" key="{5eb681ac-092e-4e69-b76a-4e3ab107af0a}" symbol="13" label="Gewerbeauffüllgebiet | Zona di completamento per insediamenti produttivi"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012303" key="{5f388f50-4960-4e07-bea9-f474abf6d3c7}" symbol="14" label="Gewerbegebiet von Landesinteresse | Zona per insediamenti produttivi di interesse provinciale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012311" key="{fad33d00-2d2b-4522-abf7-01e3ae64236c}" symbol="15" label="Zone für Schotterverarbeitung | Zona destinata alla lavorazione di ghiaia"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012312" key="{1438c7b8-22eb-43f0-a90a-53e85ca01ae4}" symbol="16" label="Zone für Abstellplätze für Lastkraftwagen und Baumaschinen | Zona per parcheggio di autocarri e macchine edili"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012313" key="{ebaf7556-2ccd-4145-b1c1-930bae2abf09}" symbol="17" label="Abbaufläche | Area estrattiva"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012320 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012360" key="{9ae2cdde-1a26-4227-ad10-da641a7a4269}" symbol="18" label=" Gewerbegebiet D | Zona per insediamenti produttivi D"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012400 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012407" key="{8611be65-3da6-4981-9e4f-ffc388512dc0}" symbol="19" label="Zone für touristische Einrichtungen | Zona per impianti turistici"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot;  > 1012500 AND  &quot;CODE&quot;   &lt;1012504" key="{7cb234da-c07d-47c5-8834-0aec7957d390}" symbol="20" label="Zone für öffentliche Einrichtungen | Zona per attrezzature collettive"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012504" key="{1353dfaa-ec8d-49ce-941e-f5f5f344f8e9}" symbol="21" label="Zone für übergemeindliche öffentliche Einrichtungen | Zona per attrezzature collettive sovracomunali"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1012511" key="{69eb386b-d1ee-4fa1-9267-3b93e70f3e90}" symbol="22" label="Militärzone | Zona militare"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013101" key="{4bf31053-1989-4162-9ca6-d47227a5391e}" symbol="23" label="Öffentliche Grünfläche | Zona di verde pubblico"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013102" key="{83a7968a-5a73-49ee-9e19-ccb274b66aa8}" symbol="24" label="Kinderspielplatz | Parco giochi per bambini"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013201" key="{a86ce984-47a7-4c7f-9e90-42420286040a}" symbol="25" label="Freizeitanlagen | Impianti per il tempo libero"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013202" key="{5622fc23-359a-48d5-b8c9-519830e62a6d}" symbol="26" label="Golfplatz | Campo da golf"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013203" key="{2001d4db-7fdb-44c8-8622-be4ff75eccbf}" symbol="27" label="Reitplatz | Maneggio"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013301" key="{03844f5b-5e01-4cc0-b92e-fb276c0b7023}" symbol="28" label="Langlaufloipe | Pista per sci da fondo"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013302" key="{2df1e326-dc2f-4fe1-9db1-bb82216e7a6e}" symbol="29" label="Naturrodelbahn | Pista naturale per slittini"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013303" key="{b0b8fee0-5355-4a71-ba26-f70b133619d9}" symbol="30" label="Skipiste | Pista da sci "/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1013304" key="{f2cf021b-7ecb-45ef-92ae-458e8c115a99}" symbol="31" label="Aufstiegsanlage | Impianto di risalita "/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014101" key="{aa434db3-0444-42ae-b5a8-363a4ef35e6c}" symbol="32" label="Eisenbahngebiet | Zona ferroviaria"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014102" key="{2ef774a6-e8ad-4171-bbe0-9e9a55f867bb}" symbol="33" label="Autobahn | Autostrada"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014103" key="{aee66bc6-cc5e-4677-be63-212bd67cf1ea}" symbol="34" label="Staatsstrasse | Strada statale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014104" key="{3943a27d-885b-4418-8b73-3d38b5afe1dd}" symbol="35" label="Landesstrasse | Strada provinciale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014201" key="{1e4814ff-8b5d-4a25-936c-dc66c7265864}" symbol="36" label="Gemeindestrasse Typ A | Strada comunale tipo A"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014202" key="{24728c83-cb0e-4239-9221-548ad91f6685}" symbol="37" label="Gemeindestrasse Typ B | Strada comunale tipo B"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014203" key="{a4906692-a5c6-4233-b677-b0d50419bbb2}" symbol="38" label="Gemeindestrasse Typ C | Strada comunale tipo C"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014204" key="{92091284-5f9e-48c9-9714-9e0ba45a97c9}" symbol="39" label="Gemeindestrasse Typ D | Strada comunale tipo D"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014205" key="{a7be3e54-ca9c-4aa2-a707-6b2414713887}" symbol="40" label="Gemeindestrasse Typ E | Strada comunale tipo E"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014301" key="{4bf733d8-6160-4f17-ba4d-6b3289ac980b}" symbol="41" label="Radweg | Pista ciclabile"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014302" key="{36b63e9a-43ea-4a5e-9996-0242d29526e5}" symbol="42" label="Fussweg | Strada pedonale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014401" key="{75c81a64-8f2b-4df8-825a-7406cabc9eb1}" symbol="43" label="Verkehrsinsel | Isola stradale"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1014402" key="{ebaf28c7-884c-4a76-a1be-95365805d0cf}" symbol="44" label="Öffentlicher Parkplatz | Parcheggio pubblico"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1015501" key="{44c97f8a-a160-43ed-b022-f604b055e262}" symbol="45" label="Zone mit Privatinitiative (Art.16 LROG Nr. 13/1997) | Zona di iniziativa privata (Art.16  LUP n. 13/1997)"/>
      <rule filter="&quot;CODE&quot; = 1015601" key="{a79dfef5-23fd-47c7-9fbc-1baa7ad4e479}" symbol="46" label="Unterirdische öffentliche Einrichtungen | Attrezzature collettive nel sottosuolo"/>
    </rules>
    <symbols>
      <symbol alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" type="fill" name="0">
        <layer pass="0" class="SimpleFill" locked="0">
          <prop k="border_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="color" v="205,205,137,255"/>
          <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
          <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
          <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
          <prop k="outline_width" v="0.26"/>
          <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
          <prop k="style" v="solid"/>
        </layer>
      </symbol>
      <symbol alpha="1"

.
.
.
.
              <text-buffer bufferSize="1" bufferSizeMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" bufferColor="255,255,255,255" bufferDraw="0" bufferBlendMode="0" bufferTransp="0" bufferSizeInMapUnits="0" bufferNoFill="0" bufferJoinStyle="128"/>
          <background shapeSizeUnits="1" shapeType="3" shapeSVGFile="" shapeOffsetX="0" shapeOffsetY="0" shapeBlendMode="0" shapeFillColor="255,255,255,0" shapeTransparency="0" shapeSizeMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeSizeType="0" shapeJoinStyle="64" shapeDraw="1" shapeBorderWidthUnits="1" shapeSizeX="0" shapeSizeY="0" shapeOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiX="0" shapeRadiiY="0" shapeOffsetUnits="1" shapeRotation="0" shapeBorderWidth="0.2" shapeBorderColor="0,0,0,255" shapeRotationType="0" shapeBorderWidthMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiUnits="1"/>
          <shadow shadowOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shadowOffsetGlobal="1" shadowRadiusUnits="1" shadowTransparency="30" shadowColor="0,0,0,255" shadowUnder="0" shadowScale="100" shadowOffsetDist="1" shadowDraw="0" shadowOffsetAngle="135" shadowRadius="1.5" shadowRadiusMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shadowBlendMode="6" shadowRadiusAlphaOnly="0" shadowOffsetUnits="1"/>
          <placement repeatDistanceUnit="1" placement="1" maxCurvedCharAngleIn="25" repeatDistance="0" distInMapUnits="0" labelOffsetInMapUnits="1" xOffset="0" distMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" predefinedPositionOrder="TR,TL,BR,BL,R,L,TSR,BSR" preserveRotation="1" repeatDistanceMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" centroidWhole="0" priority="5" yOffset="0" offsetType="0" placementFlags="10" centroidInside="1" dist="0" angleOffset="0" maxCurvedCharAngleOut="-25" fitInPolygonOnly="0" quadOffset="4" labelOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <rendering fontMinPixelSize="3" scaleMax="10000000" fontMaxPixelSize="10000" scaleMin="1" upsidedownLabels="0" limitNumLabels="0" obstacle="1" obstacleFactor="1" scaleVisibility="0" fontLimitPixelSize="0" mergeLines="0" obstacleType="0" labelPerPart="1" zIndex="0" maxNumLabels="2000" displayAll="1" minFeatureSize="0"/>
          <data-defined/>
        </settings>
      </rule>
      <rule description="Sport" filter=" &quot;RGB_UNILEG_2017_Beschreibung&quot;  =  'Zone für öffentliche Einrichtungen - Sportanlagen' " active="0" key="{b4a0d1bb-2d0c-4d9e-8d30-9b5ed3129b46}">
        <settings>
          <text-style fontItalic="0" fontFamily="Symbol" fontLetterSpacing="0" fontUnderline="0" fontWeight="50" fontStrikeout="0" textTransp="0" previewBkgrdColor="#ffffff" fontCapitals="0" textColor="0,0,0,255" fontSizeInMapUnits="0" isExpression="1" blendMode="0" fontSizeMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" fontSize="8.25" fieldName="" namedStyle="Normal" fontWordSpacing="0" useSubstitutions="0">
            <substitutions/>
          </text-style>
          <text-format placeDirectionSymbol="0" multilineAlign="4294967295" rightDirectionSymbol=">" multilineHeight="1" plussign="0" addDirectionSymbol="0" leftDirectionSymbol="&lt;" formatNumbers="0" decimals="3" wrapChar="" reverseDirectionSymbol="0"/>
          <text-buffer bufferSize="1" bufferSizeMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" bufferColor="255,255,255,255" bufferDraw="0" bufferBlendMode="0" bufferTransp="0" bufferSizeInMapUnits="0" bufferNoFill="0" bufferJoinStyle="128"/>
          <background shapeSizeUnits="1" shapeType="0" shapeSVGFile="" shapeOffsetX="0" shapeOffsetY="0" shapeBlendMode="0" shapeFillColor="255,255,255,255" shapeTransparency="0" shapeSizeMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeSizeType="0" shapeJoinStyle="64" shapeDraw="0" shapeBorderWidthUnits="1" shapeSizeX="0" shapeSizeY="0" shapeOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiX="0" shapeRadiiY="0" shapeOffsetUnits="1" shapeRotation="0" shapeBorderWidth="0" shapeBorderColor="128,128,128,255" shapeRotationType="0" shapeBorderWidthMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shapeRadiiUnits="1"/>
          <shadow shadowOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shadowOffsetGlobal="1" shadowRadiusUnits="1" shadowTransparency="30" shadowColor="0,0,0,255" shadowUnder="0" shadowScale="100" shadowOffsetDist="1" shadowDraw="0" shadowOffsetAngle="135" shadowRadius="1.5" shadowRadiusMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" shadowBlendMode="6" shadowRadiusAlphaOnly="0" shadowOffsetUnits="1"/>
          <placement repeatDistanceUnit="1" placement="0" maxCurvedCharAngleIn="25" repeatDistance="0" distInMapUnits="0" labelOffsetInMapUnits="1" xOffset="0" distMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" predefinedPositionOrder="TR,TL,BR,BL,R,L,TSR,BSR" preserveRotation="1" repeatDistanceMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" centroidWhole="0" priority="5" yOffset="0" offsetType="0" placementFlags="10" centroidInside="0" dist="0" angleOffset="0" maxCurvedCharAngleOut="-25" fitInPolygonOnly="0" quadOffset="4" labelOffsetMapUnitScale="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
          <rendering fontMinPixelSize="3" scaleMax="10000000" fontMaxPixelSize="10000" scaleMin="1" upsidedownLabels="0" limitNumLabels="0" obstacle="1" obstacleFactor="1" scaleVisibility="0" fontLimitPixelSize="0" mergeLines="0" obstacleType="0" labelPerPart="0" zIndex="0" maxNumLabels="2000" displayAll="0" minFeatureSize="0"/>
          <data-defined/>
        </settings>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </labeling>
  <customproperties>
    <property key="embeddedWidgets/count" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/addDirectionSymbol" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/angleOffset" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/blendMode" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferBlendMode" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferColorA" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferColorB" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferColorG" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferColorR" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferDraw" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferJoinStyle" value="128"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferNoFill" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferSize" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferSizeInMapUnits" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferSizeMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/bufferTransp" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/centroidInside" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/centroidWhole" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/decimals" value="3"/>
    <property key="labeling/displayAll" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/dist" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/distInMapUnits" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/distMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/drawLabels" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/enabled" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/fieldName" value="RGB_UNILEG_2017_Sym LIKE 'A%'"/>
    <property key="labeling/fitInPolygonOnly" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontCapitals" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontFamily" value="Liberation Sans"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontItalic" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontLetterSpacing" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontLimitPixelSize" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontMaxPixelSize" value="10000"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontMinPixelSize" value="3"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontSize" value="8.25"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontSizeInMapUnits" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontSizeMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontStrikeout" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontUnderline" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontWeight" value="50"/>
    <property key="labeling/fontWordSpacing" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/formatNumbers" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/isExpression" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/labelOffsetInMapUnits" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/labelOffsetMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/labelPerPart" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/leftDirectionSymbol" value="&lt;"/>
    <property key="labeling/limitNumLabels" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/maxCurvedCharAngleIn" value="25"/>
    <property key="labeling/maxCurvedCharAngleOut" value="-25"/>
    <property key="labeling/maxNumLabels" value="2000"/>
    <property key="labeling/mergeLines" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/minFeatureSize" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/multilineAlign" value="4294967295"/>
    <property key="labeling/multilineHeight" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/namedStyle" value="Normal"/>
    <property key="labeling/obstacle" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/obstacleFactor" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/obstacleType" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/offsetType" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/placeDirectionSymbol" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/placement" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/placementFlags" value="10"/>
    <property key="labeling/plussign" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/predefinedPositionOrder" value="TR,TL,BR,BL,R,L,TSR,BSR"/>
    <property key="labeling/preserveRotation" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/previewBkgrdColor" value="#ffffff"/>
    <property key="labeling/priority" value="5"/>
    <property key="labeling/quadOffset" value="4"/>
    <property key="labeling/repeatDistance" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/repeatDistanceMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/repeatDistanceUnit" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/reverseDirectionSymbol" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/rightDirectionSymbol" value=">"/>
    <property key="labeling/scaleMax" value="10000000"/>
    <property key="labeling/scaleMin" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/scaleVisibility" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowBlendMode" value="6"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowColorB" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowColorG" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowColorR" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowDraw" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowOffsetAngle" value="135"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowOffsetDist" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowOffsetGlobal" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowOffsetMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowOffsetUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowRadius" value="1.5"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowRadiusAlphaOnly" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowRadiusMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowRadiusUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowScale" value="100"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowTransparency" value="30"/>
    <property key="labeling/shadowUnder" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBlendMode" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderColorA" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderColorB" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderColorG" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderColorR" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderWidth" value="0.1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderWidthMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeBorderWidthUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeDraw" value="true"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeFillColorA" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeFillColorB" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeFillColorG" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeFillColorR" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeJoinStyle" value="64"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeOffsetMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeOffsetUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeOffsetX" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeOffsetY" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRadiiMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRadiiUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRadiiX" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRadiiY" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRotation" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeRotationType" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSVGFile" value=""/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSizeMapUnitScale" value="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSizeType" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSizeUnits" value="1"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSizeX" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeSizeY" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeTransparency" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/shapeType" value="3"/>
    <property key="labeling/substitutions" value="&lt;substitutions/>"/>
    <property key="labeling/textColorA" value="255"/>
    <property key="labeling/textColorB" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/textColorG" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/textColorR" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/textTransp" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/upsidedownLabels" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/useSubstitutions" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/wrapChar" value=""/>
    <property key="labeling/xOffset" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/yOffset" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/zIndex" value="0"/>
    <property key="variableNames"/>
    <property key="variableValues"/>
  </customproperties>
  <blendMode>0</blendMode>
  <featureBlendMode>0</featureBlendMode>
  <layerTransparency>0</layerTransparency>
  <displayfield>ELEM_ID</displayfield>
  <label>0</label>
  <labelattributes>
    <label fieldname="" text="Beschriftung"/>
    <family fieldname="" name="MS Shell Dlg 2"/>
    <size fieldname="" units="pt" value="12"/>
    <bold fieldname="" on="0"/>
    <italic fieldname="" on="0"/>
    <underline fieldname="" on="0"/>
    <strikeout fieldname="" on="0"/>
    <color fieldname="" red="0" blue="0" green="0"/>
    <x fieldname=""/>
    <y fieldname=""/>
    <offset x="0" y="0" units="pt" yfieldname="" xfieldname=""/>
    <angle fieldname="" value="0" auto="0"/>
    <alignment fieldname="" value="center"/>
    <buffercolor fieldname="" red="255" blue="255" green="255"/>
    <buffersize fieldname="" units="pt" value="1"/>
    <bufferenabled fieldname="" on=""/>
    <multilineenabled fieldname="" on=""/>
    <selectedonly on=""/>
  </labelattributes>
  <SingleCategoryDiagramRenderer diagramType="Histogram" sizeLegend="0" attributeLegend="1">
    <DiagramCategory penColor="#000000" labelPlacementMethod="XHeight" penWidth="0" diagramOrientation="Up" sizeScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" minimumSize="0" barWidth="5" penAlpha="255" maxScaleDenominator="1e+08" backgroundColor="#ffffff" transparency="0" width="15" scaleDependency="Area" backgroundAlpha="255" angleOffset="1440" scaleBasedVisibility="0" enabled="0" height="15" lineSizeScale="0,0,0,0,0,0" sizeType="MM" lineSizeType="MM" minScaleDenominator="inf">
      <fontProperties description="MS Shell Dlg 2,8.25,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0" style=""/>
    </DiagramCategory>
    <symbol alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" type="marker" name="sizeSymbol">
      <layer pass="0" class="SimpleMarker" locked="0">
        <prop k="angle" v="0"/>
        <prop k="color" v="255,0,0,255"/>
        <prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
        <prop k="joinstyle" v="bevel"/>
        <prop k="name" v="circle"/>
        <prop k="offset" v="0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
        <prop k="outline_style" v="solid"/>
        <prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
        <prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
        <prop k="size" v="2"/>
        <prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
        <prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
        <prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
      </layer>
    </symbol>
  </SingleCategoryDiagramRenderer>
  <DiagramLayerSettings yPosColumn="-1" showColumn="-1" linePlacementFlags="10" placement="0" dist="0" xPosColumn="-1" priority="0" obstacle="0" zIndex="0" showAll="1"/>
  <annotationform>.</annotationform>
  <aliases>
    <alias field="CODE" index="0" name=""/>
    <alias field="CODEALT" index="1" name=""/>
    <alias field="ELEM_ID" index="2" name=""/>
  </aliases>
  <excludeAttributesWMS/>
  <excludeAttributesWFS/>
  <attributeactions default="-1"/>
  <attributetableconfig actionWidgetStyle="dropDown" sortExpression="&quot;CODE&quot;" sortOrder="0">
    <columns>
      <column width="-1" hidden="0" type="field" name="CODE"/>
      <column width="-1" hidden="0" type="field" name="CODEALT"/>
      <column width="-1" hidden="0" type="field" name="ELEM_ID"/>
      <column width="-1" hidden="1" type="actions"/>
    </columns>
  </attributetableconfig>
  <editform>.</editform>
  <editforminit/>
  <editforminitcodesource>0</editforminitcodesource>
  <editforminitfilepath>.</editforminitfilepath>
  <editforminitcode><![CDATA[# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
QGIS forms can have a Python function that is called when the form is
opened.

Use this function to add extra logic to your forms.

Enter the name of the function in the "Python Init function"
field.
An example follows:
"""
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "MyLineEdit")
]]></editforminitcode>
  <featformsuppress>0</featformsuppress>
  <editorlayout>generatedlayout</editorlayout>
  <widgets>
    <widget name="RGB_UNILEG_2017_CODE">
      <config/>
    </widget>
  </widgets>
  <conditionalstyles>
    <rowstyles/>
    <fieldstyles/>
  </conditionalstyles>
  <defaults>
    <default field="CODE" expression=""/>
    <default field="CODEALT" expression=""/>
    <default field="ELEM_ID" expression=""/>
  </defaults>
  <previewExpression></previewExpression>
  <layerGeometryType>2</layerGeometryType>
</qgis>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What have you tried so far in order to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi, i tried to edit the existing  styles in Qgis 3.4 to see if this changes aplly, and the colours and fills appear. But nothing.

Comment: Any special symbols in the column names which might cause errors? Is the data display without your qml-style?

Comment: There are only three colums. 2 with numbers and one is empty. No special names ecc..The data is displayed without my .qml style

Comment: Is your style rule-based or categorized? Have you tried either loading a different style in 3.4 or creating a similar style?

Comment: Tis polygon style is rule-based. I have 5 other old styles (polygons, points and lines) that work under 3.4 without any problem. But these are categorized

Comment: There is most likely your answer: Your rules somehow don't work anymore under 3.4. Try building a basic rule-based style (2 to 3 rules) in 3.4 and see, what happens.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the rules you are using for the symbology that doesn't work in 3.4? It may be that some of the syntax that worked in 3.2 doesn't work in 3.4. I noticed some regexp patterns that worked in 2.18 no longer did in 3.x.

Comment: I recreated all rules "new" in Qgis 3.4 (rule-based). There seems to be a limitation of 32 rules or something. Because up to 30 something rules it worked. After that number it does not seem to work anymore and the filling and style dissappears

Comment: QGis 3.4 also fails to apply `.qml` style files to raster layers. This seems to be a more general bug.

Comment: I filed [a new bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21611) concerning raster layers. I would suggest you file a parallel report for vectors.